# Manga in which the main character has limiters on his powers, everyone forgets his existence when he does use them

Tags: story-identification, manga

I am looking for a manga in which the main character has limiters on his powers. When he uses said powers everyone forgets his existence. There were two girls who liked the main character, but had forgotten him. When he sees them again he has to reintroduce himself to them for a protection mission. He's in an academy.

Comment: Welcome to SciFi.SE! Are there any more details you can provide about this story? What medium was it? An anime? A manga? Live-action TV? How long ago did you watch it? The more details you can provide, the greater the chance we have of tracking it down.

Comment: Sounds a bit like [Forget-Me-Not from the X-Men](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/ForgetMeNot_(Xabi)_(Earth-616)). I don't think he had any limiters though - his power was always-on, causing people to forget about him as soon as they looked away from him. Professor X had used Cerebro to set up a once-a-day reminder that he existed, though, so FMN would get an occasional greeting from the Prof. It meant a lot to him.

Comment: Oh my bad I was talking about a manga

Comment: Was this set in a fantasy world, e.g. with swords and magic? Was this in black&white or full color? Do you recall about when you read this, and about how many chapters you read? In particular, are the sealed powers and/or memory loss something the MC knows about at the start, or does he find out about it later?

Comment: Take a look at [this TVTropes page](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ForgettableCharacter)